# Probability density in matlab

Tags: matlab, fft

I have a matrix (2M X 2M) consists of correlation function. Where M is the number of modes. But that matrix is in momentum space. ie, in K space. How can I convert the same into position space using Discrete fourier transform method in matlab

Comment: 2 dimensional Fourier transform is done using `fft2` and `ifft2`.